# How to call authenticated cloud functions from own server

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I created a cloud function and I want to call it from my own server.

[This help page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function) explains that I need to use `JWT`

> Service-to-function
>   If you're invoking a function from a compute instance that doesn't have access to compute metadata (e.g. your own server), you'll have to manually generate the proper token:
>   ...
>   The Cloud IAP docs have sample code to demonstrate this functionality.

And [the sample code page](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) explains that I need to use `IAP`, but `IAP` is only available for App Engine, Compute Engine, or an HTTPS Load Balancer. There is no option for Cloud functions.

> Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) lets you manage who has access to services hosted on App Engine, Compute Engine, or an HTTPS Load Balancer. Learn more
>
> To get started with IAP, add an App Engine app, a Compute Engine instance or configure an HTTPS Load Balancer.

What am I misunderstanding? How can I call an authenticated cloud function from my own server?

### Edit for more detail

I can call a cloud function with authentication in development.

```
curl https://asia-northeast1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunction -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

My server is `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS` on VPS.
I want to call the function from my Rails App.

Comment: Is your server is on GCP or not? If not, do you have a service account key file?

Comment: My server is not on GCP, and I didn't know service account key file. Should I create user-managed key? https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts

Comment: Could you please describe with details your use case so we will understand what exactly you are trying to do. How are you trying to invoke your Cloud Function, where is your server located? What do you mean by "authenticated Cloud Functions"?

Comment: @tzovourn By "authenticated Cloud Functions" I mean "HTTP functions that requires authentication". I added more detail to my question.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function) you are following is the right one. But form the second link, you only need to use the Code Sample in order to authenticate the service account you want and not the IAP. Maybe [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?_gac=1.246744752.1582892387.EAIaIQobChMIsri30Z305wIVTtTeCh35Sw4REAAYASAAEgJRUPD_BwE&_ga=2.221096600.1288870763.1584349547-1994899322.1561995857#jwt-auth) is a bit clearer regarding the second part.